# How to import a module from main env to conda env in Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, python-import, environment, conda

My main anaconda (python IDE) distribution is using `python 2.7` and has most of the modules that I typically use. I wanted to use a module that works best with `python 3`, so I created a virtual environment, say `foo`, within my anaconda using `--python=3.6` command to have `python 3`. Unfortunately, one of the modules, say `bar` that I would like to work with in the `foo` env is installed in main anaconda env and cannot be installed with `python 3.6`. I was wondering if it's possible to import `bar` in my virtual env `foo`, because `foo` uses `python 3.6` and cannot install `bar` separately?

Comment: Well, may be I am not using the correct term, but I used the conda env I think because that's how I installed it. To make it more clear, my env is located under `anaconda2/envs/foo`

Comment: As far as I know, all main installed modules are accessible via environments by default

Comment: @cricket_007 Also, my question is slightly different in a sense that I have already installed the conda env and I am asking how I can import any module from main env now.

Comment: You write the `import bar` statement like normal?

Comment: It doesn't import the modules in `foo` from the main env.

Comment: No, you cannot do this. The packages in each environment are totally separate from each other.